# how to get the last word of string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

```
mytxt = "12345678"
print(mytxt)

temptxt = mytxt[::-1]
print(temptxt)

temptxt = temptxt[0:3]
print(temptxt)

mytxt = temptxt[::-1]
print(mytxt)
```

I want to get the last 3 characters from the string, how to make this code shorter?

Comment: do you mean `mytxt[-3:]`? what is your desired output? what do you mean with "word" in your example string `"12345678"`?

Comment: mytxt = "12345678"
print(mytxt[-3:])

Comment: @hiroprotagonist omg.. yes, thank you

Comment: Even if you'd go with your overcomplicated approach… `mytxt[::-1][0:3][::-1]`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string in mytxt has the following index in each character

```
-----------------------------------------
mytxt           =  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
-----------------------------------------
index(positive) =  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
index(negative) = -8 -7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
```

The negative index allows us to access the n-last character in the string

And by utilizing the *slice* function whose syntax goes like

```
[start:end:increment]
```

so

```
print(mytxt[-3::])
```

Leaving the *initial* and *increment* blank means we're using the default value,
which are 0 for the initial and 1 for increment, or better still, just omit the second colon

```
print(mytxt[-3:])
```

The comprehensive summary of *slice* function can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [@hiro-protagonist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4954037/hiro-protagonist) you can use Python's slice notation to retrieve the last three characters of a string as follows:

```py
mytxt = "12345678"
print(mytxt[-3:])  # yields '678'
```